# Image processing for OCR with leptonica (inverse color text)

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to process the following image with leptonica to extract text with tesseract.

**Original Image:**
[image: original image]

Tesseract on the original image yields this:

```
i s l
D2J1FiiE-l191x1iitmwii9 uhiaiislz-2 Q ~37
Bottom linez
With a little time!
you can learn social media technology
using free online resources-
And if you donity
youlll be at a significant disadvantage
to
other HOn-pFOiiTS-
```

Not great, especially the top background. So using leptionica I use a background removal algorithm (blur, difference, threshold, invert) to get the following image:
[image: processed image]

But tesseract doesn't do a good job with it:

```
@@r-mair lkrm@W lh@w ilr@ mJs@ iklh@ ii@c2lhm1@ll
mm Mime
VWU1 a Mitt-Jle time-
@1m ll@@Wn Om @@@lh1
using free onhne resources-
Andifyoudoni
9110 ate a $0 D
to other non-profrts
I
```

The main problem, it seems, is that now all of the text is outlined instead of solid. How can I adjust my algorithm or what can I add to made the text solid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that this paper proposes a binarization method which solves your problem:

T Kasar, J Kumar and A G Ramakrishnan. [Font and Background Color Independent Text Binarization](http://mile.ee.iisc.ernet.in/mile/publications/softCopy/DocumentAnalysis/CBDAR_Kasar_2007.pdf). (2007)

[image: Kasar etal method performance]

Comment: That's great. Before I accept the answer, you don't happen to know of an implementation of this algorithm do you?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know if an implementation exist.

Comment: I made an implementation using python and opencv. Thanks!
https://github.com/jasonlfunk/ocr-text-extraction

Comment: that's a great effort and it looks promising but right now the text turn out like it's been dug up from some archive, basically the text is not clearly visible to the reader like you see above at far right (c)