# How to crop image so as to separate text contained on it?

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, tesseract

If you look at the attached image you'll find that, it is having image+text on it. What I want is to crop this image in such a way that text containing portion of it separates out and rest of the part is discarded. How can I do that[image]?

Comment: The state-of-the-art on this task has a f-score below 70%, be aware of that. You need to simplify your task, and it is passible of simplification in your case. Do you want to extract text from the whole image or just the browser ? Keep only the browser window. Now, you have direct access to this site. It is much simpler to make a text-only version of it by parsing its generated html. After that, get the individual images from it and work on them individually to extract text.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is very difficult. An image recognition library will get you started but it's going to be very hard to get consistent results from it. This kind of problem goes into the domain of research. Here's a blog post that might help:

http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/using-tesseract-tools-for-android-to-create-a-basic-ocr-app/

Comment: you got it right, i'm working on tesseract already and asked this for the problem that tesseract only recognises text only portions of an image otherwise returns garbage. How about clearing coloured portion of the image leaving behind only text part like asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678542/image-processing-for-ocr-with-leptonica-inverse-color-text?rq=1