# Inverted text and background colors in same image

Tags: c++, opencv

I found this question

[Image processing for OCR with leptonica (inverse color text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678542/image-processing-for-ocr-with-leptonica-inverse-color-text)

Is it possible to implement this method with openCV?

Comment: Given your reps you should know better than to ask this kind of question.

Comment: @Ron: it must be related to the Peer Pressure badge ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like someone there posted the implemntation with OpenCV.
https://github.com/jasonlfunk/ocr-text-extraction.
or you just want to invert the colors?
in the final loop in (https://github.com/jasonlfunk/ocr-text-extraction/blob/master/extract_text) they invert background and foreground colors