# extracting white and black characters at the same time using tesseract python

Tags: python, opencv, extract, tesseract

I have a table like this as you can see the characters in header are white while the characters in the body of table are black. I'm using the following code to extract this table. However, it doesn't extract the header. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or how can i get all the table extracted?

The table (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQCI9.jpg)) has a highlight header with white characters while the characters in the body are black.

```
outer=[]
for i in range(len(finalboxes)):
    for j in range(len(finalboxes[i])):
        inner=''
        if(len(finalboxes[i][j])==0):
            outer.append(' ')
        else:
            for k in range(len(finalboxes[i][j])):
                y,x,w,h = finalboxes[i][j][k][0],finalboxes[i][j][k][1], finalboxes[i][j][k][2],finalboxes[i][j][k][3]
                finalimg = bitnot[x:x+h, y:y+w]
                kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 1))
                border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(finalimg,2,2,2,2,   cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[255,255])
                resizing = cv2.resize(border, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                dilation = cv2.dilate(resizing, kernel,iterations=1)
                erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel,iterations=1)


                out = pytesseract.image_to_string(erosion)
                if(len(out)==0):
                    out = pytesseract.image_to_string(erosion, config='--psm 7')
                inner = inner +" "+ out
            outer.append(inner)

#changing the psm from 3 to 7 resolved the issue of not detecting all the values in all the cells

#Creating a dataframe of the generated OCR list
arr = np.array(outer)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(len(row),countcol))
print(dataframe)
data = dataframe.style.set_properties(align="left")
#Converting it in a excel-file
data.to_excel('output.xlsx')`
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To improve the tesseract output you should pre-process the image:
https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality . For your example, try removing the table lines + clean and invert the table head to match the rest of the text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image processing for OCR with leptonica (inverse color text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678542/image-processing-for-ocr-with-leptonica-inverse-color-text)

Comment: Thanks @Davide Fiocco, but there is not actual code in that page

Comment: True @Tazo, still https://github.com/jasonlfunk/ocr-text-extraction (from the comment left by the OP) could help.